# gtk.MessageDialog with images and background image

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I came across a function to insert image in a gtk dialog box. but there is some issue with it and not working.

```
   messagedialog = gtk.MessageDialog(parent=None, flags=0, type=gtk.MESSAGE_INFO, buttons=gtk.BUTTONS_OK,\
   message_format="Congratulations..!!")
   messagedialog.set_image('scoreimg') #line 3
   action_area = messagedialog.get_content_area()
   lbl2=gtk.Label("Awesome")
   action_area.pack_start(lbl2)
   messagedialog.show_all()
   messagedialog.run()
   messagedialog.destroy()
```

The code is not working due to #line 3. Yes, the image is available to this code.

I guess, set_image is used to set background of a dialog box. I want to add some images in dialog box (not background this time).

Also, I am trying to eliminate the "bulb" from the dialog that appears based on type=gtk.MESSAGE_INFO though I need an "OK" button.

Any idea about how I can proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is Gtk3, which is basically the same.

```
    messagedialog = Gtk.MessageDialog (None, Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL, Gtk.MessageType.INFO,\
    Gtk.ButtonsType.OK, "Congratulations..!!")

    """ Assume you have it """
    scoreimg = Gtk.Image ()
    scoreimg.set_from_file ("yourpathhere") #or whatever its variant

    messagedialog.set_image (scoreimg) #without the '', its a char
    action_area = messagedialog.get_content_area()
    lbl2=Gtk.Label("Awesome")
    action_area.add(lbl2)
    messagedialog.show_all()
    messagedialog.run()
    messagedialog.destroy()
```

A note: "set-image" property override the bulb icon (from gnome-hicolor)

Comment: Hey thanks, the bulb icon is removed but irrespective of any image that I want to set in its place, a small grey coloured circle is appearing..

Comment: I am ot sure about that, perhaps a bug in the gtk. it doesn't happen here. Try to change another gtk theme

Comment: Its working now.I had to specify the file extension too. i.e "imgname.svg"